# EXCEL VBA - Subtracting By Cell Color - Basic Subtraction Formula

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

Here is my VBA

```
Function CellColour(Irow As Integer, Icol As Integer) As Long
CellColour = Cells(Irow, Icol).Interior.ColorIndex
End Function
```

The color of the grey cells I am using is, -4142
I found this by `=CellColour(5,11)`

I currently have Two rows that contain monthly Sales data, Once the month ends I manually color the row gray, ""-4142"

I have a section for totals D6 which is a sum of a few cells
D6 = Sum(D9:D12)

What I want to accomplish is inside the D6 cell... subtract this gray number.

Cell D6 Formula:
`Sum(D9:D12)-If(Cellcolour *IN ROWS F11:Q12* = *GRAY "-4142)`

End result SUM D9:D12 MINUS WHATEVER NUMBERS ARE GRAY FROM ROWS `F11:Q12`

I think my problem lies within my inability to create the proper formula.

I feel like just doing conditional formatting might be easier?

Any help would be awesome.

Thanks!

Comment: I've played around with formula and cell colours before [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41999368/6387479) Perhaps that will help you...

Comment: Using a cell color to encode information is not a great approach: you'd be much better off with a "Status" column (which could then drive conditional formatting to add the color, but also can be more-easily used in other formulas)

Comment: most aggregate functions like sum ignore non-numeric values, so you can just prepend `'` in front of the numbers to convert them to text and hence excluding them from the sum

Answer (score 0):

Using a cell color to encode information is not a great approach: you'd be much better off with a "Status" column (which could then drive conditional formatting to add the color, but also can be more-easily used in other formulas)

That aside, your function has a problem:

```
Function CellColour(Irow As Integer, Icol As Integer) As Long
    CellColour = Cells(Irow, Icol).Interior.ColorIndex
End Function
```

...here the `Cells()` will always apply to the ActiveSheet, which may or may not be the one you expect/want.

This might explain why your "grey" cells give -4142, which is actually the code for "no fill" (xlNone)

This is more explicit in referencing the correct sheet, because you're using a Range parameter in place of numeric arguments:

```
Function CellColour(r As Range) As Long
    CellColour = r.Cells(1).Interior.ColorIndex
End Function
```

EDIT: This might be more what you need:

```
Function SumByColour(r As Range, indx As Long) As Long
    Dim c As Range, t As Double, v
    Application.Volatile
    For Each c In r.Cells
        v = c.Value
        If IsNumeric(v) And c.Interior.ColorIndex = indx Then
            t = t + v
        End If
    Next c
    SumByColour = t
End Function
```

Then you can do something like:

```
 =SUM(D9:D12)-SumByColour(F11:Q12, 15)
```